# sudo ./sakis3g not found Python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x

I need subprocess in my script to connect with 3G. But unfurtunately it's throwing me alot of errors. So I was hoping maybe someone here could help me.

My code:

```
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.run('sudo ./sakis3g connect OTHER="USBMODEM" USBMODEM="12d1:1001" APN="internet"', shell=True)
```

When I run this simple script in my home directory I get the following error:
sudo: ./sakis3g: command not found

Is it maybe because the sakis3g script itself it located in /usr/local/bin. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run this simple script in my home directory

`./` means the current directory i.e. the home directory in this case.

> Is it maybe because the sakis3g script itself it located in /usr/local/bin

`/usr/local/bin` is (likely) not your home directory. `sudo` can't find `sakis3g` in the current directory because there is no such file.

Use `/usr/local/bin/sakis3g` instead of `./sakis3g`.

Answer (score 0):

copy that saskis3g object file in your directory where you have your code then you can use the command directly without including any file path for the object file(i.e sakis3g) in your connect command.

if suppose you have a folder named sample. and your program resides in this folder then copy+paste the sakis3g object file to this folder[you can do this by using the CP command in linux ] and use the normal command ie " system("sudo ./sakis3g connect"); "  no need of any path.